# How to call another script within a script with bash

Tags: bash

Hello here is my primary script.  The test2.sh is just an echo "it worked"

what happens when I try and call from the original loop, it gets to the correct file then echo's infinite "it worked" where it should just be doing it once.

Any idea why?  I really want to have another loop called outside of the main script that won't interfere, but still learning bash =P

```
#!/bin/bash
number=1

while true
do

if [ "$number" -eq "1" ]; then
    echo "hello 1!"
elif [ "$number" -eq "2" ]; then
    echo "hello 2!"
elif [ "$number" -eq "3" ]; then
    echo "hello 3!"
elif [ "$number" -eq "4" ]; then
   ./test2.sh & continue
fi
sleep 5


((number++))
echo $number
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first observation `&` is not a logical operator, `&` runs the precedding command in the background. Use `&&` for logical operations.

what you need is a `break` keyword not a `continue` keyword . If you use the `break` keyword, the loop will stop executing. The continue keyword only rexecutes the loop , and since `number` is 4 , this branch of code will always run `elif [ "$number" -eq "4" ]; then`

**working code**

```
#!/bin/bash
number=1

while true
do

if [ "$number" -eq "1" ]; then
    echo "hello 1!"
elif [ "$number" -eq "2" ]; then
    echo "hello 2!"
elif [ "$number" -eq "3" ]; then
    echo "hello 3!"
elif [ "$number" -eq "4" ]; then
   ./test2.sh && break
fi
sleep 5


((number++))
echo $number
done
```

or you can do this

```
for number in {1..4};do
   (( number == 4 )) && ./test2.sh || echo "$number"
   sleep 5
done
```

Comment: so what I'm trying to do is continue the second script in the background but the loop still continue.  That is why I'm trying the & and continue.

Is this possible?

for some reason, it keeps echoing the second sh and never continues on counting up 5, 6, 7, etc.

Comment: @JV  You don't need the `continue`.   If you use it (it should be on the next line) then it goes straight to the top of the top again - `number` will not be incremented.

Comment: You don't need `continue` and you don't need `break`.

Comment: Oh silly me!  I had the continue there because I had an echo before I tested the second .sh file!

I see now, since I'm calling another file, I no longer need the continue!  Thanks guys :)